# Can't get gradle compatibility in Android Studio on Windows 10

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android Studio, and thanks to my dog knocking water on my Mac, I am using my PC with Windows 10 for the foreseeable future. Since I'm trying to learn Android Studio while also trying to pinpoint all the bs Windows is doing in the background, I have been beating my head against the wall for several days. To start, the PC I'm using has a 128GB SSD and a 1TB HDD, and since Windows is busy filling up my C: drive (the SSD), I am trying to keep everything else on the HDD. I originally installed Android Studio and went with the defaults, which put it on the C: drive, but when I realized what happened I uninstalled it and re-installed it on the D: drive. I also installed all the SDK tools and API versions on the D: drive.

The problem I am running into is every time I try to import a project from a tutorial, it says the project isn't synced with Gradle (these tutorials are all using older APIs and Gradle versions) and won't even give me the option to build. Originally, I set the GRADLE_HOME environment variable for the Gradle version installed on my D: drive to D:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-4.8-bin\gradle-4.8\bin and then I could at least run the gradle command without getting "command not recognized...". At that point, the new projects I had created were running fine, but any project that used an older version would not sync. I guessed that I might need to install the older Gradle versions in order to be compatible with older projects, so I installed all of them and put them in the same D:\Program Files\Gradle directory, then set that to my environment variable. That broke everything since the variable was no longer pointing to a bin folder I assume. Now when I try to import a project using Gradle external model, it doesn't matter if I select the specific Gradle path to the /bin folder on the D: drive, or if I set it to C:\Users\brand.gradle, it says 'Gradle location is incorrect'. The only way I can make the gradle command work is if I go to the /bin folder for any one of the versions I have installed, and run it from inside the directory.

I know that when Android Studio installed it put the gradle configuration in C:Users\brand.gradle, part of the reason why I thought changing the GRADLE_HOME variable might fix it. Currently, the gradle command will not work if I am in the C:\Users\brand.gradle directory. I have researched a lot but can't seem to find clear answers, especially in regards to the newest versions of everything, so here are my primary questions:

- Where does AS store and look for the gradle configuration on Windows by default (not for an individual project, but for Android Studio itself), and how can I get it to store and look for things on the correct drive?
- Do I need every gradle version installed to be able to run projects that use older versions, and if so, is there a way that Android Studio can automatically find the appropriate version if they are in the right location?

In short, I want AS to do everything on my HDD, where all of the SDKs and gradle versions are installed, but I think it is looking in the wrong places by default, and perhaps even changing things back to default values after I change them. I want this to stop, but can't figure out what it's doing.

Comment: Have you looked in File > Project Structure for any relevant settings? Maybe check in there. That's where you go to declare your compile and target SDKs, so it wouldn't surprise me if some Gradle config is in there too

Comment: If I were you, I would not be troubled to import the whole (old) project because of the errors and probably some backward incompatible features. Instead since you want to learn make a new project with a name like the one you want to import then start copying and pasting src files, and then libraries if any from app.gradle old file to your new app.gradle....

Comment: If I were you, I would not be troubled to import the whole (old) project because of the errors and probably some backward incompatible features. Instead since you want to learn make a new project with a name like the one you want to import then start copying and pasting src files, and then libraries if any from app.gradle old file to your new app.gradle....

Answer (score 0):

If you are running android Studio version 4.1.2 then go to Files -> Setting -> to
Build, Execution, Deployment, click on Gradle and it will show you the Gradle user home, it is here that you can change the directory. But make sure you copy over the Gradle files first to the external drive.